# How can I authorize Google API Client for a service account with ENV variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api-ruby-client

I am trying to authorize the Calendar API for my app. I can't get the authorization to work with the supplied .json file or by using ENV variables.

Can someone please explain to me how to do this? I would prefer to use ENV variables, but if that's not possible, then any method that works will be amazing!

This is what I have now:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => 'App Name', :application_version => '1.0.0')
      client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load
      client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
        :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        :audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
        :issuer => Rails.application.secrets.GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
        :person => Rails.application.secrets.GOOGLE_CALENDAR_EMAIL
        )
      client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
      service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
```

Comment: You should include the error you mentioned in a comment in your question, it would help to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to create environmental variable in rails. Checkout their docs for more configuration options.

Comment: The app uses the secrets.yml file for env variables so I can't use figaro. The ENV variables are no problem though, I already have them set. The google API authorization is the problem as it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If you are comfortable adding a screenshot, then that is way more clearer as one would know what line is raising that exception. Obviously `nil` errors are usually caused by something missing.  Be sure everything is provided. You can pry into your code to see if everything is set, or check the line number where the exception is raised. To help you debug this.